# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. external login with twitter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

It's an asp.net mvc5 application. Still under development. I am using 'twitter' login.
When I click on 'login with twitter', it just throws an error on the screen.
This is pretty weird because everything was working good and all of a sudden I see this error.

The only thing changed is when i started my computer, it said system date changed and asked me to press 'f1' and change the date. I did it.
I am not sure if that has something to do with the error.

The error is attached. Would be great if someone can show some light

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Credit goes to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011890/owin-twitter-login-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validati)
anyone who has the similar issue, plz follow the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Default code snippet.

[image]

Just Replace the above code snippet with the one given below in **Startup.Auth.cs** class and replace your own **Consumer Key** and **Consumer Secret**.

```
app.UseTwitterAuthentication(new TwitterAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ConsumerKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            ConsumerSecret = " XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ",
            BackchannelCertificateValidator = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.CertificateSubjectKeyIdentifierValidator(new[]
            {

              "A5EF0B11CEC04103A34A659048B21CE0572D7D47", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
              "0D445C165344C1827E1D20AB25F40163D8BE79A5", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
              "7FD365A7C2DDECBBF03009F34339FA02AF333133", // VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary CA - G5
              "39A55D933676616E73A761DFA16A7E59CDE66FAD", // Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
              "‎add53f6680fe66e383cbac3e60922e3b4c412bed", // Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
              "4eb6d578499b1ccf5f581ead56be3d9b6744a5e5", // VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5
              "5168FF90AF0207753CCCD9656462A212B859723B", // DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server C‎A 
              "B13EC36903F8BF4701D498261A0802EF63642BC3"  // DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
            })
        });
```