# The remote certificate is invalid with Twitter sign in

Tags: asp.net, twitter, asp.net-identity

Following [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) and [this](http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/linkedin/) I was able to get ASP.NET Identity to work with Google and LinkedIn sign in, but I'm having trouble with Twitter.

I set up an app on Twitter, but it won't take `localhost` (since I'm just doing dev right now) as a valid URL for website and callback URL, so I tried:

```
https://127.0.0.1:44301
```

and

```
https://127.0.0.1:44301/signin-twitter
```

Which let me register my app. But in my ASP.NET application, when I click the twitter button to log on I get:

```
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

So how do I get Twitter to play nice when running on my dev (`localhost`) machine? Google and LinkedIn had no problems whatsoever.

Comment: I've had exactly the same problem this week - the solution is a combination of MichaelLake's and webStuff's answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011890/owin-twitter-login-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validati). Use MichaelLake's answer for the code, and webStuff's for the latest thumbprint.

Comment: @PhilPursglove: Thanks for that. Absolutely spot on. I'll close this question down.